# Error NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext in Intellij community

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, pom.xml

This is my full error. I use the newest IntelliJ IDEA Community, JDK 20. When I run, it show the message below (I deleted show unnecessary code):

```
    com.rdsic.quan_ly_goodchild.QuanLyGoodchildApplication.main(QuanLyGoodchildApplication.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528]
    
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted

2024-01-05 17:34:18.463  WARN 14720 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@76ed5528]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Beside, there was some error with my pom.xml file:

```
Plugin 'org.springframework.experimental:spring-aot-maven-plugin:0.10.3' not found
Dependency org.graalvm.buildtools:junit-platform-native:${native-buildtools.version} not found
Plugin org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:${native-buildtools.version} not found
```

Edit: I downgraded my JDK to JDK 1.8 and now it's work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're using an outdated setup. It's now `jakarta.servlet`

Comment: I really dont wanna change the code much. So can I use the older ver of something?

Comment: Not without running into problems - like you already *have* done

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://endoflife.date/spring-boot), your current (`2.5.5`) Spring Boot version does not support JDK 20:

| Release | Java |
| --- | --- |
| 3.0 - 3.2 | 17 - 21 |
| 2.7 | 8 - 21 |
| 2.6 | 8 - 19 |
| 2.5 | 8 - 18 |

So you need to **downgrade your JDK to JDK18 or lower** or **upgrade Spring Boot to 2.7, or newer**.

If you ask me, I would upgrade Spring Boot to **3.2.x**, or **3.1.x** and go with an LTE JDK Release, **JDK 17** or **JDK 21**.

Comment: I downgraded to JDK 8, but it still have error:

IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
Caused by: NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext

Comment: I see. Is it possible to share your `pom.xml`? If so, please edit your question with the pom.xml, or at least the dependencies you are using. Thank you!